# How to get path of a captured image in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-bitmap

I am working on an android application. It has a functionality that captured image should display on screen and I need to get that image path, so that I can send that image to server.

I am able to display image on screen, but unable to get absolute image path.

I am getting path like:

```
content://media/external/images/media/1220
content://media/external/images/media/1221
```

How can I get actual image path?

Here is my code:

```
mintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                 MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
startActivityForResult(mintent, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if ((data != null && !data.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Intent {  }"))
      || requestCode == 1)
    switch (requestCode) {
      case 1:
        try {
          // Uri imageFileUri = data.getData();
          // String path=getRealPathFromURI(this,imageFileUri);
          // Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

          String photoPath = null;
          Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Media.class);
          intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);

          Bundle b = mintent.getExtras();
          if (b != null && b.containsKey(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)) { // large
            // image?
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            // Shouldn't have to do this ... but
            photoPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Img" + timeStamp
                        + ".jpeg", null);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

`photoPath` value is shown in above.

How can I get my absolute image path from this path.

Answer (score 4):

**A complete working solution**

```
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
private String imgPath;

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });


public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: how come nobody accepted this answer...Thanx a lot Biraj... the most amazing solution I found in all...keep it up...!!!

Comment: managedQuery takes five parameters as `Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, String[], null);`  you have passed null so it is giving error any thought?

Answer (score -2):

on camera button

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));


        try {

            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Do nothing for now
            }
```

and on activity result write

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

             if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
              // Bitmap photo1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                 File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                   Bitmap bitmap11 = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file1.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 300);
                  // 
                    }  
    }
```