# Set gallery image as button background

Tags: android, button

I have a button in my code to take a picture:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cameralogo"

            android:id="@+id/buttonCamera" />
```

When i click it it opens the camera and saves a picture, path is String mCurrentPhotoPath;

after the camera intent was displayed i want the button to show the image as background (android:background="mCurrent.....")???

how do do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

You cannot set background only by path or URI, you'll need to create a Bitmap( and use ImageButton) or a Drawable out of it.

Using Bitmap and ImageButton:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
yourImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Using Drawable and Button:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
yourButton.setBackground(d);
```

Comment: Yep you need to use it in an activity or use Context instance: context.getContentResolver(). By the way, if you find my solution helpful than please rate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this question yet?
[How to set the button background image through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397788/how-to-set-the-button-background-image-through-code)

You cant do this in the xml but only programmatically. Just get a reference to the newly created picture like described here:
[How to get path of a captured image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856601/how-to-get-path-of-a-captured-image-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

**To start the camera intent:**

```
...
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
...
```

Where PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE is just a integer constant unique within activity to be used as request codes while starting intent for results.

**To Receive photo in the onActivityResult, and update background of the view**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        if (photo != null) {
            // mView should refer to view whose reference is obtained in onCreate() using findViewById(), and whose background you want to update
            mView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does not use full size photo. For that, you will have to ask Photo intent to save it to a file, and read the file. Details are present[here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)